# How to write a correct zipfile checksum value, and make it as part of zipfile content

Tags: java, algorithm, checksum

Currently, my app will perform zip process on list of files on disk, and allow user to send as email attachment for backup purpose.

To have data corruption detection capability, I generate checksum by using the following method

```
public static long getChecksum(File file) {
    FileInputStream stream = null;
    CheckedInputStream cis = null;
    try {
        // Compute Adler-32 checksum
        stream = new FileInputStream(file);
        cis = new CheckedInputStream(stream, new Adler32());
        byte[] tempBuf = new byte[128];
        while (cis.read(tempBuf) >= 0) {
        }
        long checksum = cis.getChecksum().getValue();
        return checksum;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "", ex);
    } finally {
        org.yccheok.gui.Utils.close(cis);
        org.yccheok.gui.Utils.close(stream);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tend to embed the checksum info as filename

```
myapp_12-dec-15_3659593860.zip
```

To me, the filename is not really human friendly,

I wish I can have the filename like

```
myapp_12-dec-15.zip
```

If I want to achieve so, I need to write the checksum in a text file, and make it as part of zip file content.

However, this creates a paradox.

1. If I write the checksum file into the zip file, the previous computed checksum will no longer be valid.
2. If I want to compute the checksum only after writting checksum file into zip file, what should be the content of checksum file?

Comment: Would a nested ZIP file be a solution? If so, you can create a ZIP file containing exactly two files - the intended ZIP file and its checksum file.

Comment: The .zip file format [already includes a CRC-32 checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#File_headers), so I'm not sure why you think you need a separate checksum of your own.

Comment: The built-in CRC-32 checksum won't help for my purpose. Say, my app generate the zip file based on 3 files. User may modify the content of zip file manually, by adding an additional file. Having a pre-computed checksum, enable me to know, whether this zip file is generated by app originally, or modified by users.

Comment: So, in reality, you want to avoid tampering, then you need a seal. CRC is not a good solution: it is not secret, then also easy to tamper. you should think about cryptography, hash, and mac functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your making your own checksum computation and validation algorithm, I think you can make the following assumption: zip files contain data and metadata. Data is the files the user has selected from his disk. Metadata is the file with the checksum of the data, also available in the zip.

Then the checksum is not computed from the complete zip file, but from the user's data only, then adding it to a zip file does not change the checksum.

Answer (score 2):

Zip format supports checsums by itself. `ZipEntry` class (if you use it) has CRC-related functionality:

```
  ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));

  String fileInZip = "mytext.txt";
  ZipEntry e = new ZipEntry(fileInZip);
  e.setCrc(calcCRC(fileInZip));
```

That will add crc checksums to each file in archive.

Another option will be add 32-bytes-long crc checksum (for example) to the end of zip file. On file check you should read last 32 bytes of archive for checksum, then calculate crc of archive without that 32 bytes and compare with provided checksum.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach workable for me.

1. Produce **data.zip**
2. Compute checksum of **data.zip**, and write it into checksum.txt
3. Zip **data.zip** + **checksum.txt** together as **myapp_12-dec-15.zip**

---

```
myapp_12-dec-15.zip
    |
    |____ data.zip
    |
    |____ checksum.txt
```